# InvalidOperationException: The constraint reference ' Guid' could not be resolved to a type

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, entity

I am able to build this .NET5 project but on browser it is showing "The constraint reference ' Guid' could not be resolved to a type."

[image]

I Am expecting how to resolve Guid type here.I have given the ID of string type in Repository files.[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space:

```
[Route("{id:Guid}")]
```